# Why MiniDumpWriteDump can be generating invalid dumps?

Tags: c++, windows, windows-10, windbg

I wrote code that should write dump. It creates valid dump files on simple test applications (I tested them they work), but dumps generated by real application aren't loaded by Visual Studio and WinDbg (even by debug build).

From WinDbg:

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 10.0.17030.1002 AMD64
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


Loading Dump File [C:\Users\Dmitrii\temp\MidiDump.dmp]
Minidump does not have system info
Could not open dump file [C:\Users\Dmitrii\temp\MidiDump.dmp], HRESULT 0x80004005
    "Unspecified error"

The debugging session could not be started: FAILURE HR=0x80004005: Failed to open dump file: C:\Users\Dmitrii\temp\MidiDump.dmp
Couldn't parse command line parameters: FAILURE HR=0x80004005: Failed to open dump file: C:\Users\Dmitrii\temp\MidiDump.dmp
```

Any idea what could be causing these errors?

Comment: When I've run into this issue in the past, it's been a permission issue. Is the process calling `MiniDumpWriteDump` running with elevated privileges? (Try setting [MANIFESTUAC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384691.aspx) to requireAdministrator.) Also, are you calling `SetPrivilege(hToken, SE_DEBUG_NAME, true);` on the current process or current thread token before opening the process handle to dump?

Comment: Another possible reason that I've come across is when the crash was caused by the process leaking memory until the host machine ran out of RAM and had to kill the process in self-defense.  In that scenario, the process's memory space is so large (and the amount of RAM available to facilitate saving it to disk is so small) that the MiniDump functions are unable to save the .dmp file properly.